# Not able to set TextColor with ColorDrawable

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView and its default color is set as

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Now in order to get a new textcolor from the preferences I did the following:

```
textcolor = Color.BLACK;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences5 = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
textcolorpri = sharedPreferences5.getInt("tabletextcolor", textcolor);
```

but I'm not able to set this color to text, getting an error with the below code

```
textView.setTextColor(new ColorDrawable(textcolorpri));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTextColor` expects a *color* as an `int`.

`new ColorDrawable` will create a `Drawable` which is an object.

---

If you want to use the color, just use `textView.setTextColor(textcolorpri);`

Also see the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)).

Comment: I donot know when I tried it at first go it did not work earlier and now on ur guidance, it worked like.